# docbook get rid of second page

Tags: pdf-generation, docbook, docbook-5

I generate documentation with docbook. The output is pdf

Given this simple example,
How can I get rid of the page between the front-page and the toc, that shows the title and author a second time?

Alternatively, an `<article>` with a front-page or title-page is also ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Docbook XML V4.1.2//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd">
<book lang="en">
  <info>
    <author>
      <personname>John Doe</personname>
    </author>
    <title>Test</title>
  </info>
  <chapter>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

my makefile:

```
REPORT_NAME=test
XML_REPORT=$(REPORT_NAME).xml
PDF_REPORT=$(REPORT_NAME).pdf
FO_REPORT=$(REPORT_NAME).fo
XSL=/usr/share/xml/docbook/stylesheet/docbook-xsl-ns/fo/docbook.xsl

all:    
    xsltproc --stringparam paper.type A4 \
         --stringparam  section.autolabel 1 \
         --stringparam page.margin.inner 1.0cm \
         --stringparam page.margin.outer 1.5cm \
         --stringparam body.start.indent 1pc \
         --stringparam fop1.extensions 1\
             $(XSL) $(XML_REPORT) > $(FO_REPORT)
    fop -fo $(FO_REPORT) -pdf $(PDF_REPORT)
```

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/9407275/407651

Comment: Btw, since you use Docbook 4, the `docbook-xsl` stylesheets are a better choice than `docbook-xsl-ns`. See http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ProcesingDb5.html#Db5Xslt.

Comment: @mzjn this does the trick. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an unwanted second title page when processing docbook to PDF via fop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407275/getting-an-unwanted-second-title-page-when-processing-docbook-to-pdf-via-fop)